# nodejs + mongo + find + $and error: Can't canonicalize query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

the query is:

```
{$and:[
    {phone:phone},
    {$gte:{date:'2014-08-25'}},
    {$lt:{date:'2014-08-30'}}
]}
```

and then it shows an error:

```
{ [MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $gte] name: 'MongoError' }
```

What's the meaning of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your whole query structure is not correct really. Operators act on "fields" in a argument form. So the operator is a "value" to the field as a "key" in a manner of speaking.

Aside from that "all" MongoDB queries are in fact implicitly an "and" query. The [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator itself is only required where you are specifying multiple conditions for the same field. But this is not how you do a "range query" with [**`$gte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) and [**`$lt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) operators, but rather you "combine" them in the same "operator document":

```js
db.collection.find({
    "phone": phone,
    "date": { "$gte": "2014-08-25", "$lte": "2014-08-30" }
})
```

Also worth noting here that this only works where your dates are actually "strings". What you really "should" have are "date objects" in your collection, which generally represent in the shell like so:

```js
ISODate("2014-08-29T17:51:30.428Z")
```

This will help you greatly as you can do other things with dates and similarly do not need to "convert" these for any other manipulation in your code. When you have actual "date objects" then you query them by simply using other date object instances like so:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "phone": phone,
    "date": { "$gte": new Date("2014-08-25"), "$lte": new Date("2014-08-30") }
})
```

Comment: exactly, I think more people need to realize that MongoDB queries are not JSON, but BSON: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
{date: {$gte: '2014-08-25'}}
```

and likewise for the `$lt`

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/#op._S_gte